Почему возникает ошибка переобьявления одной и той же переменной в разных областях видимости в VS Code?
Если модуль имеет свою область видимости отличную от глобальной, то почему в данном примере появляется ошибка переобьявления переменной?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Я запустил локальный сервер npx serv... Повторил твой пример и открыл его в браузере http://localhost:8000/tmp.html - никаких ошибок нет. Вот если убрать type='module' - тогда ошибка в консоли есть.

Даже по протоколу file:///C:/tmp/tmp.html ошибок тоже нет...

Нужно больше информации: структура проекта, какие плагины подключены, есть ли дополнительные проверяльщики?

@ksa, проверил в vscode - действительно есть проблема

@Grundy, да, там подчеркивает как ошибку. Видать не различает еще "модульные" скрипты.
